# Cannot use IPA phonemes with Google Home SSML

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, ssml

Alexa has the capability to speak phonetically using the IPA phonemes...example below

```
<speak>
    You say, <phoneme alphabet="ipa" ph="pɪˈkɑːn">pecan</phoneme>. 
    I say, <phoneme alphabet="ipa" ph="ˈpi.kæn">pecan</phoneme>.
</speak>
```

I cant see this support anywhere in Google Home..anyone know if Googles SSML supports this?

Comment: I have the same question and concern. This is very important and should be supported to correct pronunciations. Google, please add this ASAP.

Comment: #actions-on-google
According to the W3C SSML spec (https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/#S3.1.10), the phoneme element is *required*. This is a critical missing feature. We have many words that Google's TTS engine does not pronounce correctly and we're unable to correct it. It looks like the element is completely ignored, not even pronouncing the words between elements. E.g., it does not even pronounce "baseball" in <phoneme>baseball</phoneme>. Google, please address this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it looks like Google Assistant does not support this tag yet.
I also find this frustrating because my responses have a lot of names in them which are being read out incorrectly.

Currently the documentation for Google's SSML is defined here:
https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml

See the following caveat on this page:

> Note that not all of the elements and options described in the W3 SSML
>   specification are currently supported by the Actions on Google
>   platform. This page details which elements and options are available
>   for your application. The W3 reference links provided below may be
>   helpful for additional context and examples.

Unfortunately, there is no mention of "phoneme" support.

However Google does provide some additional features not in the standard SSML reference such as the  tag (parallel audio responses).

One way you can work around this issue is to make use of the SUB tag.
You can substitute an alias phrase to replace the content inside the tag.

An example of pronouncing Daniel Ricciardo's name as he does:-

```
<speak>Daniel <sub alias=\"Rickardo\">Ricciardo</sub></speak>
```

See the following link for more information:
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html#sub

Answer (score 0):

The Actions on Google platform [now supports the phoneme tag](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/ssml-beta).